# Svd and Eigen decomposition of Matrices

Tags: matrix-multiplication, eigen, svd, square-root

My question is about Singular Value and Eigen Decomposition for any matrices.
For any matrice A, let say my SVD is A = UDW' and my Eigen Decomposition is A = BCinv(B).
Let take a real number x, under some assumptions A^(x) = B.C^(x)inv(B).
How can I obtain A^(x) with SVD decomposition?

Thanks

Comment: This might be more appropriate for Computational Science Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would like to construct some real power of a matrix A, `A^(x) = B C^(x) inv(B)`, where `B C inv(B)` can be obtained by eigen decomposition. 
The short answer is that the matrices U, W given by a singular value decomposition are usually not the inverse of each other https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320232. That is, they would not "cancel out" in the constructed matrix power function. There is no clear way how to contruct a real matrix power function with SVD.

Only when A is symmetric, SVD becomes similar to an eigen decomposition (up to permuting the values). But then you could well stick to eigen decomposition.